# Windows Phone 7 - directions to place

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I am looking for solution which can be working for both WP7.1 and WP8. I was searching and I guess I can't use [Driving directions for WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Codesample), am I right? I tried to use [MapsDirectionsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but even If I added references to needed thing still It can't resolve symbol. So I guess for WP7 it's [BingMapsDirectionsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394024%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I get my application run but when I tried to find directions from my location to address I get error that directions wasn't found. So what could be wrong? I tried multiple address, with or without geocoordinate and so. Did I need download to my phone something first? Are there any restrictions to use Bing maps directions? Is there a better way to have directions working in WP7?

Edit:
I tried codes from MSDN examples for MapsDirectionsTask and BingMapsDirectionsTask. As I wrote I can't get MapsDirectionsTask working because VS can't find out reference for that (but I added libraries which are mension in article).

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
// here I tried different addresses and I tried to add geocoordinates to these addresses            
LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("Space Needle", null);
bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = spaceNeedleLML;
bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

Bing maps just say that can't find directions

Comment: Please share (code) what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

when map loads tap on any location it gives you direction from your current location to tapped location.

Try This, This takes from location as your current location and to location is where you tapped on the map, replace ur content inside namespace by this code, this works fine

```
        public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadWatcher();
    }

    private void LoadWatcher()
    {
        if (watcher == null)
        {
            watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
            watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;

            watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
            watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        }

        watcher.Start();
    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        myMap.SetView(e.Position.Location, 10);
    }

    void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                statusTextBlock.Text = "location is not functioning on this device";
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                statusTextBlock.Text = "Initializing";
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                statusTextBlock.Text = "location data is not available.";
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                statusTextBlock.Text = "location data is available.";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void map1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition(myMap);
        var geoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate();
        geoCoordinate = myMap.ViewportPointToLocation(position);

        OpenDirectionTo(geoCoordinate);
    }

    private void OpenDirectionTo(GeoCoordinate locationY)
    {
        BingMapsDirectionsTask directionTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
        directionTask.End = new LabeledMapLocation("Your tapped location", locationY);
        directionTask.Show();
    }
}
```

Refer this Article 
[***Directions***](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd80b9/getting-direction-in-windows-phone7-application/)